# Why there is not a rename column command in mysql?

Tags: mysql, syntax

We need to rename a column in mysql with the lengthy,

`alter table table_name change old_name new_name column_def`.

Why not follow the syntax,

`alter table table_name rename old_name new-name`?

Comment: Referential integrity is based on the table name.  DDL changes can be very expensive in time and effort to QA, and should provide some insight to why DBAs act as they do.

Comment: MySQL ... ISAM ... integrity? Haha. Mkay :-) It's just an implementation detail of MySQL compared to other vendors (the reason(s) is(/are) debatable but not very interesting) -- it would be sort of interesting if SQL-xx DDL conformance was thrown in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the reason is that when you rename, you effectively change the type of the attribute as well. So change is more accurate :)

Comment: I'd say its a part of usual mysql sloppiness: they could restore the omitted column type form table's metadata. But I must shut up now lest a flame war happens :)

Comment: @SpyrosP well that doesn't explain why mysql couldn't simply implemented a rename functionality

Comment: there is no straight explanation of course. It's just convention whatsoever. rename would be like unix cp, as described in the question. However, mysql follows different conventions and so alter table seems pretty close to the general syntax.